# libgdx desktop project is catching the back key

Tags: java, android, libgdx, desktop

I'm making a game using libgdx. In the android build for the game I want to catch the back key and pause the game. In the desktop build i want to catch the escape key to pause the game.

I've done this in a previous game by just catching both the escape and back key in the base project (no platform specific code). So there's not much to show for relevant code:

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(mStage);
Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);
if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.BACK) || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.ESCAPE) )
{
    mPaused = true;
}
```

The problem i'm having was that the desktop version of my game seemed to be getting stuck paused sometimes. Putting a breakpoint on the above condition when it got stuck I found out that the `Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.BACK)` part of the condition was always true.

At first i thought it was only happening when i was pressing escape, but it seems like I can press any key and it will eventually cause the BACK button to get stuck on (i.e. it doesn't get stuck the first press but after 10-15 key presses, of any key, it gets stuck).

From what i've searched with libgdx, i thought that the BACK key was specifically for android and that there isn't an equivalent button for PC.

I know I could easily modify the code so the desktop version only catches the escape button, but i'm more interested in why this could be happening.

What can cause libgdx to catch the BACK key on PC?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like both `BACK` and `META_SYM_ON` have the same keycode (4).  See http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/constant-values.html#com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys.BACK.

I'm not sure where these numbers are coming from, but I suspect they are from the underlying platform (Android or LWJGL), so the overlap is probably unavoidable.

I'm not sure what `META_SYM_ON` corresponds to (one of the ALT keys?) so this may not be relevant.  But it does seem like you should stick to checking platform-specific keys only on the relevant platform (since there is no guarantee that that key isn't something else on another platform).

Answer (score 0):

In your case it would be a lot better to look for the keyDown event rather than checking every frame for the state of a certain key. Try this aproach:

```
    InputProcessor backProcessor = new InputAdapter() {
        @Override
        public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {

            if ((keycode == Keys.ESCAPE) || (keycode == Keys.BACK))

                // Some code

            return false;
        }
    };

    InputMultiplexer multiplexer = new InputMultiplexer(mStage,
            backProcessor);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(multiplexer);
```